# Flex Mobile StyleableTextField Truncate Text Based on Orientation

Tags: android, ios, flash, apache-flex, flex4.6

I am creating an ItemRenderer for a list component in a Flex application. In my item renderer I have a `StyleableTextField` which contains a short description of the current item in the list. If this comment gets to long (as it probably will) I would like to truncate it with a `...` on the end.

It it possible to do that with the `StyleableTextField`? Also, if the device is rotated, I would like the truncation to change to new width. Is that also possible?

I suppose the second would be possible if the first is possible. All I have to do is listen for a `StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING` event.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StyleableTextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/StyleableTextField.html) has a public method

```
truncateToFit(truncationIndicator:String = "..."):Boolean
```

that truncates the text to make it fit horizontally, and appends an ellipsis (...) to the text.

Another option is to use [LabelItemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/LabelItemRenderer.html) which truncates its text automatically (via build-in StyleableTextField) and adds ellipsis marks. You can use LabelItemRender as is or extend it to implement your custom LabelItemRenderer.

Some more reading on how to extend LabelItemRenderer:

- [LabelItemRenderer Multiline text support.](http://flexponential.com/2011/08/21/adding-multiline-text-support-to-labelitemrenderer/#more-979)
- [Extending LabelItemRenderer to look like iTunes on the iPad](http://flexponential.com/2011/06/27/extending-labelitemrenderer-to-look-like-itunes-on-the-ipad/)